# Logitech MK270 keyboard lagging

Tags: windows-10, logitech-keyboard

A month or so ago, I bought a Logitech MK270 wireless keyboard and mouse that I use on my work and home PCs.

My work PC seems to be fine but, on my home PC (Windows 10 64-bit v2004) and ever since the beginning, the keyboard regularly gets "stuck" for a few seconds, particularly when playing games. Portal 2 seems to be even worse when playing co-operately online, somehow.

I've looked into this and the common causes seem to be:

- Distance between the USB receiver and the devices. I can't see how it could be this as there's only a light desk and ~50 cm between them.
- Interference. My Wi-Fi AP is downstairs but I use my work PC in the same place so both should be affected if it was that.
- Battery. Again, it seems to work fine with my work PC so it's probably not this.
- Resource spikes. I've had Task Manager open on my second monitor while playing and I've observed no correlation.
- Drivers. I was using the default Windows ones so I installed SetPoint 64-bit version 6.69.126 from https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360025141274 which did replace the devices and drivers but it didn't resolve the problem.

**Update 2020/09/07 21:36:** Using a USB hub to ensure that there's nothing obstructing the keyboard and the USB receiver does seem to have drastically improved the problem but, as previously mentioned, the most noticeable scenario is when playing Portal 2 co-op and my Partner In Science is unavailable for over a week so I'll report back then.

Comment: The wireless receiver is either Bluetooth or 2.4 GHz.  If it's 2.4 GHz and your access point is also 2.4 GHz that could explain the behavior.  More information would be required to answer this question though

Comment: You get one of these pairs (I have one similar Logitech here) with a single USB Receiver that you plug into a USB port. Is the second receiver a Logitech receiver (also known good)?

Comment: i solved my similar problem with short extender for the USB Dongle to my Logitech.

Comment: Yup - first test, move the dongle. USB extension cables are cheap.

Comment: Thanks all. I've ordered a USB 3.0, 4-plug hub anyway so I'll test it with that and update this with my findings.

Comment: I'm having this problem now, even with fresh batteries. https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91iIjC5%2BvCS.pdf looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now confirm that using a USB hub to bring the receiver in line of sight of the devices seems to have resolved the problems.

Comment: This may have been the answer for me too, so +1. My tiny USB receiver was plugged into a Rybozen USB 3.0 switch only ~60 cm away from my keyboard, and then I moved it closer to ~40 cm away, and I don't think I had a problem after that. Then, for other reasons, I replaced that switch with a different one (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405017/how-can-2020-16-macbook-pro-output-to-2-displays-that-also-get-used-by-a-pc-s/408139?noredirect=1#comment570353_407014), so I don't know if that was a factor too.